# Set Text Customization in TextView

Tags: android, textview, customization

I have a text that is sometimes too high and at times one word.

[image]

How to put the text in this TextView so that the first two lines are located around the specified spacing?

Should this be done by 2 TextView?

If yes, how can I figure out how much text is placed on the top two lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) to add customizations to a string inside a TextView.

The styling android blog has an excellent post about it: https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

But looking to your print, it seems that the first row will always have a style and the rest another. With this, using two TextViews and customizing the view directly is a better option for code and performance.